# How can I insert content between the 2nd and 3rd paragraphs in HTML, using Perl?

Tags: html, regex, perl

I'm trying to match the point between 2nd and 3rd paragraphs to insert some content. Paragraphs are delimited either by `<p>` or 2 newlines, mixed. Here's an example:

> text text text text
>   text text text text
>
> `<p>`
>   text text text text
>   text text text text
>   `</p>`
>   <--------------------------- want to insert text here
>   `<p>`
>   text text text text
>   text text text text
>   `</p>`

Comment: what language are you using? e.g. javascript?

Comment: the language is perl, but i'm limited to regex only, no scripting can be done - this is in context of a template language.

Comment: The constraints you have are nice things to note in your question.

Comment: Is this a standard template tool, or a custom one you guys have cooked up?

Answer (score 3):

Assuming there are no nested paragraphs...

```
my $to_insert = get_thing_to_insert();
$text =~ s/((?:<p>.*?</p>|\n\n){2})/$1$to_insert/s;
```

should just about do it.

With extended formatting:

```
$text =~ s{
    (             # a group
        (?:       # containing ...
            <p>   # the start of a paragraph
            .*?   # to...
            </p>  # its closing tag
        |         # OR...
           \n\n   # two newlines alone. 
        ){2}      # twice
    )             # and take all of that...
}
{$1$to_insert}xms # and append $val to it
```

Note, I used \n\n as the delimiter; if you're using a windows style text file, this needs to be `\r\n\r\n`, or if it might be mixed, something like `\r?\n\r?\n` to make the `\r` optional.

Also note that because the '\n\n' is after the `|`, the `<p>` blocks can have double newlines in them - `<p>` to `</p>` takes priority.  If you want newlines inside the `<p>`'s to take priority, swap those around.

Comment: +1: Capturing a non-capturing group? That's gonna take some getting used to. Oh, you might need to add the `/s` modifier if you're to match `\n` with `.`

Comment: Also brought in the part about the double newline.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a regular expression, use an HTML tree walker to find the second paragraph and add whatever you like. I talked about this sort of thing in my [Process HTML with a Perl module](http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1581075) article for InformIT.

The advantage of something like [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder) is that you deal with the logical structure of the HTML rather than contending with the position and order of random characters in a regular expression. If the structure stays the same, a tree walker should keep working. If you change almost anything, the regex is probably going to break.

An [HTML::TreeBuilder](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-TreeBuilder) example looks something like this:

```
#!perl
use strict;
use warnings;

use HTML::TreeBuilder;
use HTML::Element;

my $html  = HTML::TreeBuilder->new;
my $root  = $html->parse_file( *DATA );

my $second = ( $root->find_by_tag_name('p') )[1];

my $new_para = HTML::Element->new( 'p' );
$new_para->push_content( 'Add this line' );

$second->postinsert( $new_para );

print $root->as_HTML( undef, "\t", {} );

__END__
<p>
This is the first paragraph
</p>

<p>
This is the second paragraph
</p>

<p>
This is the last paragraph
</p>
```

If you need to clean up your data first, you can throw in some steps to use [HTML::Tidy](http://search.cpan.org/dist/HTML-Tidy) with the `enclose_text` option.

Comment: I was caught by this mistake too, but there's two problems. The question specifically mentioned that it has to be a regex - "the language is perl, but i'm limited to regex only, no scripting can be done - this is in context of a template language."  In addition, two newlines also count as a 'new paragraph' - HTML::TreeBuilder can't know about that requirement since it's not a valid HTML paragraph.

Comment: Actually, the template stuff is hidden in a comment.

Comment: Ok, that point conceded.  However the "two newlines counts as a paragraph" requirement is still a problem.

Comment: For that, I'm go through all the templates and make them valid HTML. Building solutions on broken situations is just more future pain.

Answer (score -1):

Text:

```
my $text = '
text text text text
text text text text

<p>
text text text text
text text text text
</p>
<p>
text text text text
text text text text
</p>
';
```

This should work with:

```
our $cnt = 0;
our $where = 2;

my $new_stuff='<- want to insert text here';
$text =~ s/
           (
            (?:\n|<\/p>)\n
           )
           (?{ ++$cnt })
           (??{ $cnt==$where?'':'!$' })
          /$1$new_stuff\n/xs;
```

Result:

```
text text text text
text text text text

<p>
text text text text
text text text text
</p>
<- want to insert text here
<p>
text text text text
text text text text
</p>
```

Regards

rbo

Comment: Instead of downvoting (don't be stupid, it costs you a point) please give advice what's wrong with the answer and how to do better. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't do the downvote, but I suspect it has to do with the fact that he needed a regex only solution, and this needed variables.

Comment: @Robert, I see, I missed that. Thanks!
rbo